# After upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 I have no desktop

Tags: upgrade

I have desktop icons but no sidebar and no jammy jellyfish wallpaper or the wallpaper I had with 20.04 also no menu bar to shut down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean Reinstall 20.04 from dvd iso then upgrade worked fine .I Just hope backup restores!